# How to get both partial view and JSON data from jquery ajax call in MVC5?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have to get a partial view to render items and get json data to update a dropdown.
How to get both partial view and JSON data from jquery ajax call in MVC5?

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way to do this would be to have the server side code render the partial view and return to the ajax request as a string, and then get the ajax success method to replace the html.

something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "your url of endpoint",
    data: {your data},
    success: function (response) {

        $('your div to replace').empty().append(response);
    },
    error:function(){
        //handle any errors
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to get both partial view and JSON data. I've updated the question.

Comment: i that case then, what you'd need to do is return a JSON object, containing the JSON and the html as string

so your endpoint would return something like

return JSON( new { html = html, jsonData = jsonObject});